# jQuery tableExport plugin - preserve carriage returns

Tags: jquery, excel

I have built a html table which I can export to EXCEL using the jQuery.tableExport plugin. My requirement is to have carriage returns in certain cells to represent different products. See layout below:

```
# ORDER     PRODUCT
1 12345     Pens
            Books
            Badges
2 67890     Knives
            Pans
            Erasers
```

However, I have tried to separate the Products with 
, enclose in

tags, and also use \r\n to try and break these. The plugin however seems to ignore all of this and just renders them in a line, as follows

```
# ORDER    PRODUCT
1 12345    PensBooksBadges
```

Has anyone got a solution to this. I didn't particularly want to have to generate duplicate rows in the Excel table, but this may be the only way of displaying the products in a nested manner.

I'd appreciate any help, or suggestions for an alternative plugin perhaps?

Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate `CHAR(10)` between each two products.

Here is an example:

Set A1="Hello" and A2="world"

Then:

`=A1 & A2` produces `Helloworld`, whereas

`=A1 & CHAR(10) & A2` produces

`Hello
 world`

Take into account that for this to work, cell must have "Wrap text" option enabled:

*Cell format* -> Alignment -> *Wrap text*